# AngularJS + Ngingx CORS

Tags: angularjs, nginx, cors

Im trying to have the following setup:

**API**

api.domain.com

**APP**

domain.com

I've setup 2 different nginx configs, one for each of the 2 urls.
Both of them work when doing regular GET requests in the browser (api.domain.com/test) but it all falls apart when doing a $resource call from angularjs (POST). This returns a

```
     not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I've been going on this for a while now and been playing around with different config files.
I'm currently using the following file but i have no idea if this should work.

http://paste.laravel.com/h6U

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Is the OPTIONS call completing as expected (200 returned if you use chrome devtools)? If yes and the subsequent POST fails, it seems to be missing some headers and a status code on the server side...

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this [post](http://mercenarytech.com/2013/01/nginx-and-angularjs-routes/).

I'm also new to angularjs. And I write my back-end code with nodejs. When tried to use the api by the backend in frontend with angularjs, I met the same problem like you.

So I use nginx to store my app, and then in my `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` file I can change the router with nginx, and in this way can avoid the problem caused by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

For CORS to work with in Angular JS, try adding this config to your application's angular module

```
angular.module('simpleRESTapp')
.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
        delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
}])
```

For the Nginx side,you'll need to configure nginx or your application server to return an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header containing the value of the `Origin` header sent by the client if it matches the allowed list. I guess this config should work,

```
if ($http_origin ~ "^(http://developers.example.com|http://example.com)$") {
    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" $http_origin;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with angularJs and Nginx
so I added bellow codes to my nginx config. the important things that i found after lots of search is that [always] key. the point of using [always] key is that when i used code without always I got no error status codes and i just got 200 and 201 the other status codes get cross origin error.

```html
 add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' http://127.0.0.1 always;
 add_header 'Access-Control-Allow_Credentials' 'true';
 add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,Accept,Origin,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range,Access-Control-Allow-Origin';
 add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE,PATCH';
```